# How to locate the pagination select button using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, html-select

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = r"https://www.nba.com/stats/players/advanced"
driver.get(url) 

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, r"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/div/select"))

select.select_by_index(0)
```

No matter everything I try I cannot find this full Xpath. I just want the code to recognise the little button that goes from page 1 to all to view all player stat on single page.

I've looked into similar questions but unable to get it solved.

Snapshot:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: how can we help if you don't add the xpath and the html/page?

Comment: image didn't upload copy pasted code

Comment: Which element are you trying to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it seems that the path is not working, the better way to start solving the problem is to gradually remove tags from left to right while in the inspector tool. By removing `/html/body/div[2]` from your xpath I was able to find the element in the HTML

```
xpath = "//div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/div/select"
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath))
```

which if I understood correctly is this one

[image]

Comment: but what do you mean by "inspector tool to delete tags from left to right". do you mean within my code itself (trial and error) or within inspect website, if so where?

Comment: @de4dhe4d00 Yes I mean inspect the website, if you right click and click Inspect, the browser opens a tool to inspect the page where you see the HTML right? Then press CTRL+F and paste `//div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/label/div/select`

Answer (score 0):

To recognise the little button that goes from page 1 to all to view all player stat on single page and select the an option within the [website](https://www.nba.com/stats/players/advanced) you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get('https://www.nba.com/stats/players/advanced')
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'Pagination')]//div[contains(., 'Page')]//following::div[1]//select")).select_by_index(0)
```